# Retrieve current selected object in Sparx EA with SQL

Tags: enterprise-architect

In SQL, I would like to retrieve the object currently selected in the Project Browser.

```
select 
    obj.ea_guid as CLASSGUID,
    obj.object_type as CLASSTYPE,
    obj.*
    from t_object as obj
    where obj.object_ID = #OBJECTID#
```

Is there a special word for this ? Similarly to `#PACKAGE#` that works to get the id of the currently selected package, I tried `#OBJECT#`, `#OBJECTID#`. But none of these are working.

Or any other approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `#CurrentElementID#` as documented in the [manual](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_navigation/creating_filters.html)

Comment: Just above: **Curent**ElementGUID. LOL